# Use $out to insert into collection withougt wiping it first

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

According to the documentation, using $out in MongoDB's aggregation framework is wiping any existing data before writing.

Is there any way to force it not to remove existing documents but only add to the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the aggregation framework doesn't have such a feature. You can either write a map reduce job which, if I remember correctly, can append to a collection or you can have the aggregation job return a cursor which you can iterate over and then update your collection.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up inserting the data into a temporary collection after each aggregation so at the end I a single collection with all the aggregation results.